# What causes this error "API violation - cannot set inverted on <unitTestName> after already waiting on it"?

Tags: swift, xcode, xctest

I am writing some unit tests and when I go to run the tests they crash on `wait(for: [expectation], timeout: timeout)` with the following error.

"API violation - cannot set inverted on  after already waiting on it"?

What would cause this error?

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out. I was calling `expectation.isInverted = false` multiple times in my unit test.